# Double While Transac SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, while-loop

I´m having some trouble about this query. The problem is that only one while is process, the firts one, don´t work for me.

This is my code: 
The While @j, don´t work, but I don´t see the mistake ...

Thanks for your time.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertVar
AS

DECLARE @i int
DECLARE @j int

SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET @i = 1
SET @j = 1

    WHILE @j < 21
        BEGIN
            WHILE @i < 11
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO Var(idline,idVar,CheckBox ) 
                    VALUES(@j,@i,0); 
                    SET @i = @i + 1;
                END;
        SET @j = @j + 1;
    END;

SELECT * FROM Var;
GO
```

Comment: Don't do this You Loop Take too Much Time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are other ways to do this logic (such as a single query).  But your problem is that you do not re-initialize `i` inside the loop.  Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertVar
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @i int;
    DECLARE @j int;

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET @j = 1;

    WHILE @j < 21
        BEGIN
            SET @i = 1;
            WHILE @i < 11
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO Var(idline, idVar, CheckBox) 
                        VALUES(@j, @i, 0); 
                    SET @i = @i + 1;
                END;
        SET @j = @j + 1;
    END;

    SELECT * FROM Var;
END;
GO
```

Comment: @Mohit Pointless setting ` NOCOUNT OFF` at the end of the proc. Exiting the proc will reset it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Recursive CTE` to generate the rows. No need to use `while loop` or `declaration of varaiables`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Insertvar
AS
  BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

        ;WITH cte
             AS (SELECT 1 AS idline
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT idline + 1 FROM   cte
                 WHERE  idline < 20),
             cte1
             AS (SELECT idline,1 AS idVar,0 AS CheckBox
                 FROM   cte
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT idline,idVar + 1,CheckBox FROM   cte1
                 WHERE  idVar < 10)
        INSERT INTO [Var]
        SELECT * FROM   cte1
        ORDER  BY idline,idVar 

      SELECT * FROM   [Var]
  END
```